Can't get running instance of Outlook and New Interop.Outlook.Application opens Outlook as administrator not windows user
Since removing previous x86 office and installing Office 2019 64Bit
oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

no longer works when Outlook is already running and if not running then oOutlook = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application() Opens an instance of Outlook in a window which requires 2 clicks on the maximize to make it maximize. I have the Outlook object library in references and the following imports
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Imports Redemption

If I only use the line to create a new instance of outlook without closing the currently open instance it opens a new visible instance. When I clicked on the search field I get the message that instant search is not available when running with administrator permissions.

I have tried the following options without success. None gets the running instance or opens Outlook as it should when opened by the user. The project is also set to not prefer 32Bit.

        Try
            'Dim procs() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Outlook")
            'If procs.Count > 0 Then
            'oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            'Dim outlookType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application")
            'oOutlook = Activator.CreateInstance(outlookType)
            oOutlook = DirectCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
        Catch
            'Else
            'oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            oOutlook = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()
            'End If
        End Try

I've read so much on this that my brain is now fried & am desperate for a solution so any guidance/assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Are you forcing your project to run as x64?
You can't and don't want to use ANY CPU, since then what bit size your application runs as is "left to the wind and chance". So, force your project to also run and match the bit size of office, and no code changes should be required.
In other words, the fact of changing from x32 office to x64 bits should not change anything, but DOES require you to change the bit size of your running .net application to match the same bit size used for office.
Edit: You cannot use the new version of outlook
Having stated all of the above, keep in mind that office builds now have a option to use the "new" outlook, and that new version of outlook does not support COM object automation. That means CreateObject, and GetObject can't work, and will not work.
That option is this:

So, if this option is turned on, then x32 or x64 bit office and Outlook does NOT matter, it will NOT work no matter what you do.

Morning Albert, great to see you again. You helped me quite a bit when I was teaching myself Access.

I've changed the VS configuration to use Active(x64) platform & Target CPU as x64 without success. The GetObject & CreateObject methods don't work (I've read this is deliberate by MS on the latest versions of Office apps. If I try this "oOutlook = DirectCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)" or this "oOutlook = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()" to get the Running copy of Outlook I get the error 0x80080005 CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE. If I close Outlook then it opens an instance as administrator

If I click on instant search I get a window "is not available when Outlook is running with administrator permissions. To use instant search, exit and restart outlook without administrator permissions."

Forgot the @Albert

Take a look at my edit. You can NOT use nor turn on the "use new outlook" option.

the Office I have is desktop 2016-2019 x64. I saw on my laptop a popup referring to the NEW Outlook which I had read about & don't want to make use of it anyway. At this stage I'm considering going back to my previous x86 older version of Office if it's going to get me past all these hastles Just worry that the user that will ultimately use this app might upgrade to my current version then what do I do. I did read about some issue if the version was ClicktoRun. I found a ClicktoRun key in the registry. Could that be part of my issue?

Hum, no I don't think click to run from vb should matter.  As long as the vb build matches office then no changes should matter
